# Align bullet points in two side-by-side itemized lists

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, itemize, minipage

I'm trying to create two side-by-side bullet point lists in a document, where each point lines up with the corresponding point in the other list, even when one of the points has multiple lines.

So far I use a minipage environment and `\\` the items to where they are side-by-side, but this seems like a major kludge.

As an example, I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Mary had a little lamb,
\item Old MacDonald had a farm,
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Her fleece was white as snow. And everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go.
\item E-I-E-I-O! And on this farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O! With a moo moo here, and a moo moo there.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the code snippet above]

and then to align them I add `\\`s as appropriate

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Mary had a little lamb, \\ \\
\item Old MacDonald had a farm,
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Her fleece was white as snow. And everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go.
\item E-I-E-I-O! And on this farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O! With a moo moo here, and a moo moo there.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Items aligned with backslashes]

But is there a more sane way to do this? Notably this stops working whenever I use `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not concerned about page breaking, I'd just set this in a `tabularx`. It's all about the column specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% Loads the array package
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    @{\hspace{1.5em}}% Space for left bullet
    >{\leavevmode\llap{\textbullet~}\raggedright}% Left bullet + formatting of column
    X% Left column specification
    @{\quad\hspace{1.5em}}% Space between columns + right bullet space
    >{\leavevmode\llap{\textbullet~}\raggedright\arraybackslash}% Right bullet + formatting of column
    X% Right column specification
    @{}% No column space on right
  }
  Mary had a little lamb, & 
    Her fleece was white as snow. And everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go. \\
  Old MacDonald had a farm, & 
    E-I-E-I-O! And on this farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O! With a moo moo here, and a moo moo there.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned, the column specification is the important thing here. Technically we only have 2 `X`-columns, each of which have a space of `1.5em` on the left of it that is used to place a `\textbullet` inside. The look is similar to that of an `itemize`. The two columns have an additional `\quad` between them.

With the correct setup, the code for your construction should be fairly easy to read/interpret, and therefore be easily maintained.

---

Content can also be stretched vertically by [adjusting `\arraystretch` accordingly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764). Headings and other `tabular`-related constructions are also easy to add, for example, the use of [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcommand{\fakeleft}{\multicolumn{1}{X}{}}
\let\fakeright\fakeleft
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Vertically stretch tabular constructions
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    @{\hspace{1.5em}}% Space for left bullet
    >{\leavevmode\llap{\textbullet~}\raggedright}% Left bullet + formatting of column
    X% Left column specification
    @{\quad\hspace{1.5em}}% Space between columns + right bullet space
    >{\leavevmode\llap{\textbullet~}\raggedright\arraybackslash}% Right bullet + formatting of column
    X% Right column specification
    @{}% No column space on right
  }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering\bfseries Left heading} &
    \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering\bfseries Right heading} \\
  \midrule
  Mary had a little lamb, & 
    Her fleece was white as snow. And everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go. \\
  \fakeleft & 
    This is a right bullet without a left counterpart. \\
  Old MacDonald had a farm, & 
    E-I-E-I-O! And on this farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O! With a moo moo here, and a moo moo there. \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

`\fakeleft`/`\fakeright` can be used interchangeably to produce a bullet without its opposite counterpart.

Comment: Is there also a way to add a heading/title on each of the lists? I realize I forgot to add that to my example.

Comment: Also is it possible to have multiple bullet points on the right aligning to a single left-hand point (or creating a dummy on the left)?

Comment: @RogerFilmyer: I've added some more stuff to the answer to accommodate your requests.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for forgetting this stuff when I asked the initial question!

Comment: Okay! It looks great!
2 minor questions with the code:

Comment: 1. If I want to left-align my headers, the left header aligns well with the bullets, but the right is offset. What variables do I tweak to get it to line up?

Comment: 2. It looks like the entire table is indented, relative to text. How can I get it to line up?

Comment: @RogerFilmyer: 1. For the headers left-aligned with text, use `\multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{1.5em}}l}{\bfseries Left heading} & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries Right heading}`. For headers left-aligned with bullets, use `\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries Left heading} & \multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{-1.5em}}l}{\bfseries Right heading}`

Comment: @RogerFilmyer: 2. You'll note I used `\noindent` before `\begin{tabularx}` to avoid any indentation typically inserted by the paragraph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20653/discussion-between-roger-filmyer-and-werner).

Comment: @Werner: loading `ltablex`, you solution will break across pages.

Answer (score 7):

You can try with the [`multienum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multenum) package, by defining a new `multiitem` environment

```
\newenvironment{multiitem}{%
  \multienumerate\renewcommand{\labelname}{\textbullet}%
}{%
  \endmultienumerate%
}
```

No need for `minipage`s or `tabular`s with it.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multienum}

\newenvironment{multiitem}{%
  \multienumerate\renewcommand{\labelname}{\textbullet}%
}{%
  \endmultienumerate%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multiitem}
\mitemxx{Mary had a little lamb,}{Her fleece was white as snow. And everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go.}
\mitemxx{Old MacDonald had a farm,}{E-I-E-I-O! And on this farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O! With a moo moo here, and a moo moo there.}
\end{multiitem}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this using the parcolumns package, often used for side-by-side translations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk{\centering Left Header}
\colchunk{\centering Right Header}
\colplacechunks
\colchunk{\begin{itemize}\item Mary had a little lamb,\end{itemize}}
\colchunk{\begin{itemize}\item Her fleece was white as snow. And everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go. \item Another right bullet under the same left bullet.\end{itemize}}
\colplacechunks
\colchunk{\begin{itemize}\item Old MacDonald had a farm,\end{itemize}}
\colchunk{\begin{itemize}\item E-I-E-I-O! And on this farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O! With a moo moo here, and a moo moo there.\end{itemize}}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```